# TinyMCE attaches then disappears when using jquery modal dialog and MVC.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have an MVC.net page with a button that opens a jquery modal dialog. I open my dialog like this

```
$(dialogId).dialog(
            {
                dialogClass: 'test', closeOnEscape: true,
                title: title,
                height: height,
                width: width,
                minHeight: minHeight, maxHeight: maxHeight,
                minWidth: minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth,
                resizable: resizable,
                modal: true,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'blind',
                open: addTinyMCE
            });
```

addTinyMCE is a function that lives in my partial and the partial is the content for the modal. The add tiny MCE code looks like this

```
function addTinyMCE() {
        $('#emailMessage').tinymce({
            script_url: '/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "myButton,autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

            theme_advanced_buttons1: "xedomenubutton,undo,redo,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,

            skin: "o2k7",

            template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js"            
        });
    }
```

myButton is a tinyMCE button which I have created for some custom actions.

When I click the button on my main page to open the dialog, the dialog opens as expected but the  tinymce editor flashes against the textarea within the partial dialog popup and then returns to a normal textarea. The partial also has a drop down list that when changed, updates the content of the tinymce textarea (ajax) and again, the textarea appears with the tinymce editor attached and then returns to a normal textarea.

Also, with this being a modal dialog, when should the following commands be called to create and add the custom button.

```
tinymce.create
tinymce.PluginManager.add
```

When I try attaching the editor to a textarea in my main page, everything works as expected (editor attaches to text area, custom button is displayed and functions correctly).

Any suggestions?

I'm using the jquery version of the tinymce editor.

EDIT:

I eventually went back to using the jquery version of tinyMCE as it was functioning far better with the UI Dialog than the standard version.

I've managed to get my custom button loading in correctly and the editor is available when i close and open the dialog.

The only issue i'm left with is that on first open of the dialog, tinyMCE attaches to the textarea and then vanishes. I decided to put within my document ready function

```
setTimeout(function () { initTinyMCE(); }, 500);
```

and this works, interesting but not a solution.
So it seems that there is a timing issue here.

How can I ensure that the textarea is ready to take the tinymce editor or is the tinymce init firing too early?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the jQuery version, so this is a shot in the dark.  The regular version cannot be lazily loaded via Ajax.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=66531#p66531

The hack I've used, which has not been extensively tested, is run this:

```
window.tinyMCEPreInit = {base : 'your/js/folder/tinymce', suffix : '', query : ''};
// Lazily load your TinyMCE javascript
window.tinymce.dom.Event.domLoaded = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery tinymce build is a source of problems and it is slow. I advise to to use the regular tinymce build and addionally loading jQuery.

The custom button should be initialized at initialization. THis can be done using an own plugin or the setuop initialization paramter.

Comment: I went back to using the standard tinyMCE editor and it works great the first time I open the modal but the second time it's opened, the editor doesn't attach properly to the textarea and when I click on my custom button, i get two dropdown lists. It's like everytime i open the dialog it initialises a new tinymce editor and the old one isn't being killed off?

Comment: thats right, you have to shut down the "old one" correctly using: tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');

Comment: I added close: function () { tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, '#emailMessage'); } to my dialog close function but the editor still functions the same way, doesn't init properly (after the first open) and if i open and close the UI Dialog 3 times, i get 3 duplicated dropdowns within the tinymce editor custom button (this was why I started to look at the jQuery version).

Comment: hmm, that sounds wierd. Can you open a jsfiddle.com demo ? that would help

Comment: I'm also seeing an error in firebug when i try and submit the data in my partial Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]. the error happens when i try tinyMCE.triggerSave(); Sorry, not used jsfiddle.com what is it?

Comment: using jsfiddle.netyou can share runable code and provide a problem case. example: http://jsfiddle.net/R2rHn/5/ . at what time do you call triggerSave()?

Comment: I'm trying to call the trigger save when the dialog is closed so either in the ajax success callback, or closure of the dialog should be both). The trigger save works in chrome but not in firefox, weird.

Comment: hmm, that is pretty wierd indeed

Comment: more developments, see edit to main post. Thanks again for helping with this :-)